# ConstraintLayout: Compound ImageView that stays in parent when text expands

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-constraintlayout

Consider the following layout:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="Text" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/text_view"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:background="@android:color/black" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The image view (or button, or any other widget, important is that it has a fixed size) is aligned right/end of a TextView with a size of wrap_content, thus, the text itself only takes the space it needs.

What I now want is, when the text expands (aka if it's longer), that the button gets aligned to the right of the parent, and the text view only gets the width that is left and gets ellipsized.
At the moment, the image view is pushed outside and the text gets ellipsized once it fills the whole parent.

I tried to fix this by adding a endToEnd="parent" constraint the the image and setting the horizontal bias to 0 (see code), but that doesn't work.

Any suggestions on what I could do instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to prevent the `ImageView` from getting pushed outside the parent you need to constrain the end of the `TextView` to the start of the `ImageView` to create a chain. Now to ensure that the `TextView` only takes the space it needs but also has its constraints enforced, you need to add `app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"` attribute to your `TextView`.

If you want the `ImageView` to stay immediately to the right of the `TextView`  can use `packed` chain style with a horizontal bias of `0`.
If you want the `ImageView` to be aligned to the right of the parent you can use the `spread_inside` chain style without bias.

The resulting XML with above changes might look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/image_view"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="Text" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/text_view"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:background="@android:color/black" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**EDIT:** As requested in the comment, here's how it would work with a `Barrier` sparating the 3 `TextViews` and the `ImageView`. In this case you don't specify the constraints for the ends of the `TextViews` thus you no longer have them chained horizontally. Instead, you create a `Barrier` with the direction being the `end` of all `TextViews` that are referenced in the `Barrier`. This will ensure that the `Barrier` is always at the end of the widest `TextView`. The last thing to do is to constrain the start side of the `ImageView` to the `Barrier`.

Example XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/text_view2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="Text1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/text_view3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/text_view1"
        tools:text="Text2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/text_view2"
        tools:text="Text3" />

    <android.support.constraint.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="end"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="text_view1,text_view2,text_view3" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/barrier"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:background="@android:color/black" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked! Since I posted a highly simplified version of my layout, do you know how that could also work with barriers? I have in fact 3 text views aligned vertically, and a barrier on their right side separating them from the image. It seems however, that chaining the barrier and the image view together is not supported - the layout gets completely messed up.

Comment: @Maxr1998 I've updated my answer to explain this case too.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I've tried as well, sadly, it doesn't work with the barrier in between - the image gets pushed out of the parent like I described above. Any other ideas?